# Widget that makes use of the configuration activity and onUpdate for subsequent updates in Android

Tags: android, android-widget, android-service, android-appwidget

Actually I am trying to make simple weather app for android. I have used the configuration activity "WeatherAppWidgetConfigure" which makes use of shared preferences to choose different cities(they are stored as string-array in resources) and when I add the widget, it displays the weather forecast of that city. So far I did that and the different instances of the widgets show the respective weather forecast. But I want to implement an update functionality (update button) in this widget which updates the weather for that widget. I have failed miserably on doing this. Here I used "MyWeatherAppWidgetProvider" which extends AppWidgetProvider from where I try to invoke the service class "UpdateWeatherAppWidgetService" to get done what I need. Link to my previous code is here [how to perform widget update by service after clicking a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778799/how-to-perform-widget-update-by-service-after-clicking-a-button)

In "WeatherAppWidgetConfigure" I took some reference from http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/appwidget/ExampleAppWidgetConfigure.html

where I don't understand why should I use:

```
// Find the widget id from the intent.
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        mAppWidgetId = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,
                AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
```

since I have not explicitly called WeatherAppWidgetConfigure from anywhere. In fact I can reach the service class just when adding the widget but not while clicking the update button.